# How to copy data having only two iterators?

Tags: c++, stl

I am creating a merge sort algorithm, and one of the steps of the algorithm involves creating subarrays that are part of the sequence over which the sort is performed. As input, I get the iterators at the beginning and end of the container, then finding an intermediate iterator between the beginning and the end, then it is necessary to copy the data based on the received iterators.

```
  template<class Iterator>
    void merge_sort(Iterator t_begin, Iterator t_end)
    {
      // Recursion ends when the sequence becomes 1
      if(std::distance(t_begin, t_end) < 2) {
        return;
      }

      // Combining two sorted sequences
      auto merge = [](Iterator begin, Iterator middle, Iterator end) {
        // Supposed, subarrays are sorted
        const std::deque<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*begin)>> left {begin, middle}, right {middle, end};

        auto left_it = left.begin(), right_it = right.begin();

        // Merge two subarrays into one sorted
        for(Iterator itr = begin; itr != end; ++itr) {
          if(left_it == left.end()) {
            *itr = *right_it++;
          } else if(right_it == right.end()) {
            *itr = *left_it++;
          } else if(*left_it <= *right_it) {
            *itr = *left_it++;
          } else {
            *itr = *right_it++;
          }
        }
      };

      Iterator middle = t_begin + static_cast<std::size_t>((std::distance(t_begin, t_end) / 2));
      merge_sort(t_begin, middle);
      merge_sort(middle, t_end);
      merge(t_begin, middle, t_end);
    }
```

As a solution I use explicit declaration of the queue data structure.

```
const std::deque<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*begin)>> left {begin, middle}, right {middle, end};
```

How can having two iterators copy the data to another variable without binding to a specific container, and use for example the one to which these iterators belong? Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: No, there probably isn't a more elegant way.  If you want to copy the data, you have to use a container.  You can leave the choice to the user by taking a container or an allocator.

Comment: Unrelated, but it would be more efficient to use `vector`s instead of `deque`s.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for isn't just a C++ thing, it's an algorithmic thing. Mergesort implemented in the default (and fastest) way requires extra temporary memory.

There are ways to avoid this, known as *in-place mergesort* or simply *in-place merging*. It is highly non-trivial though, search around and you'll find multiple algorithms to do this.

Comment: Yes, I understand that in STL there is a function (std:: merge) which combines two sorted ranges, and which will solve my problem better than the lambda function written by me. But the question is aimed precisely at how having two iterators to get a copy of the data without being tied to a specific container. So if in the future there will be a similar situation, I knew how it can be solved correctly. Thanks for the suggested ways, I will definitely study these points.

Comment: @DmitryEmelyanov I wasn't talking about `std::merge` at all. Anyway, in C++ you are responsible for memory management, there isn't a construct "store this but I don't care what container" in C++. In those scenarios `std::vector` should be your default choice, it is the simplest container for storing a simple sequence of elements.